Can eavesdroppers see when one opens MetaMask with a password (and does nothing else)?
Person wants to keep his web identity decoupled from his MetaMask wallet and uses a trustworthy VPN.
Person forgot to activate VPN and opened MetaMask with his password, realizes VPN is not active and doesn't do anything in MetaMask.
Is person's identity compromised?
Which web traffic is there between MetaMask and blockchains?

TCP/IP?
SSL/TLS?

I read RPC, or JSON-RPC in MetaMask docs. Is that in plain text or over a secure tunnel?
Sources about Ethernet web traffic, and crypto in general, are also welcome.
Edit: MetaMask is used as a browser extension.

Adding to @Ismael answer, MetaMask logs to sentry.io.  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network can be used to see what calls are made.  This question leads to: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/165106/ethereum-desktop-or-mobile-wallets-for-privacy

Somewhere in Metamask documentation it is mentioned that the RPC provider, for example Infura, have access to IP and address when sending a transaction.
Metamask uses third party services for scam and theft protection. Those services might have access to IPs and addresses. Usually they are enabled by default but could be disabled from the configuration.
Communication between Metamask and RPC providers is through https so that should prevent eavesdroppers.
