Ethereum desktop or mobile wallets for privacy
Are there any Ethereum wallets or forks designed for user privacy?
A desktop or mobile wallet that only makes calls to a local node, and has logging disabled by default?
Is there a fork of MetaMask that removes or disables logging to places like sentry.io?
